# Tasting the meaty Shabbos food on erev Shabbos Chazon: can one swallow?

Tags: food, cooking-bishul, meat, nine-days, erev-shabbat

We do not eat meat or poultry in the Nine Days with certain exceptions notably Shabbos.
It is customary to taste the Shabbos cooking on erev Shabbos afternoon to check the flavouring. 
During the nine days, is it necessary to spit this small quantity of food out or can one swallow it?
I once asked a shaaloh and was told it is permitted to swallow but must not eat a large amount. I recently heard in a shiur that it’s better not to swallow the food. CYLOR of course but where does the argument originate?

Comment: Does one make a bracha if one knows one will spit it out? Presumably so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Shmiras Shabbos Khilchasa 42:61 on Erev Shabbos during the Nine Days, you may also taste the food. However, one should try not to swallow food containing meat ingredients

Comment: Rabbi Neustadt in his most recent "A discussion on the three weeks" quotes the Mekor Chayim 551:9 to say, "A woman who needs to taste the Shabbos foods while cooking may do so on Friday afternoon after midday". Since he does not mention spitting out the foods like the sources brought by the Shmiras Shabbos Khilchasa, I assume she may swallow the food. I could not find which Mekor Chayim this is. Can someone help please?

Comment: See the note there where the SSK indicates that when Rosh Chodesh falls on Erev Shabbos (like this year, 5775), it should be fine to swallow the food.

Comment: Don't see how this answers "where does the argument originate".

Answer (score 2):

In the sefer Tshuvos Avigdor Halevi (Rav Nebontzal) page 390:24 he holds even to taste is assur.

Comment: Don't see how this answers "where does the argument originate".

Comment: How is it worse than a siyum or Kos Shel Bracha? Tasting food lekavod shabbos is certainly a mitzva.