# May one give a child a Meat meal on Erev Shabbos Chazon if they are always served on Erev Shabbos a meat meal?

Tags: halacha, meat, nine-days

Inspired by [Tasting the meaty Shabbos food on erev Shabbos Chazon: can one swallow?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17707/tasting-the-meaty-shabbos-food-on-erev-shabbos-chazon-can-one-swallow)

Per Mishna Berura 551:70 it is not permitted to feed children meat during the 9 days unless the child is weak. May one give a child a Meat meal on Erev Shabbos Chazon if they are always served on Erev Shabbos a meat meal? Perhaps this is considered their Shabbos meal where they may be allowed to eat meat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Igrot Moshe OC IV 21:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=37) if that is the usual time they eat their Shabbat meal because they don't stay up late until after maariv, then they may consume meat as usual.

Comment: אלא מאכילין אותן סעודת שבת בשעה או כשתי שעות קודם קבלת שבת יכולין אז להאכילן בשר

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: What about if it's not their "shabbos seudah" but simply what they feed the child on early friday afternoon during "lunch time" ...

Comment: @Yehoshua IMHO it seems from the Teshuva that that would not be ok.

Comment: @DoubleAA From the teshuva yes, however halacha l'maseh I would disagree.

Comment: @Yehoshua Ok, well I'm just presenting RMF's position here. If you have more sources feel free to present them. I'm not sure why you'd disagree though. Lunch on Friday isn't a Mitzva.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding about what age of a child we are dealing with.