# Can one eat meat on erev shabbos in the 9 days for the mitzvah of טאמאה?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, meat, tisha-bav, erev-shabbat

I remember learning once that it is a mitzvah to taste at least one food on erev shabbos that will be served on shabbos. I believe it is called טאמאה.

So today is erev shabbos Rosh Chodesh during the 9 days. Am I permitted to do this mitzvah like every other week with something fleishigs?

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily a duplicate since Rosh Chodesh is a special case that could be more lenient. (See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17707/tasting-the-meaty-shabbos-food-on-erev-shabbos-chazon-can-one-swallow#comment167042_17712)).